# CMakeLists.txt. Setting a macro from a program output

Tags: c++, git, cmake

I'm Making the portability of a code to CMake. The code needs that CMake defines Macro with last short head from git.

If I define the value manually,

```
target_compile_definitions(LibDEFINES PRIVATE
    GITVER=3686e892
)
```

There is no problem, the code compiles, only with a warning

```
317:13: warning: floating constant exceeds range of ‘double’ [-Woverflow]
             .arg(GITVER)
         ^
```

The problem comes when I try to extract automatic the macro value from the git command

```
execute_process (
    COMMAND bash -c "git rev-parse --short HEAD"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_VER
)

message(WARNING "MyMSG\t" ${GIT_VER})    //Prints to console the right value 3686e892

target_compile_definitions(LibDEFINES PRIVATE
    GITVER=${GIT_VER}
)
```

but, I guess, the variable is not well defined, because, the compile process, stops with a strange error and yet compiles fine when is manual defined

```
A_Typedef.h:552:5: error: ‘Sem’ does not name a type
     Sem*   semPS;
```

My first assumption is that GIT_VER is declared like string, but I have no idea, perhaps I don't use the right procedure to Set the macro.

How should I correctly define the macro from git command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get rid of warning you should prepend 0x. It is now treated as float in scientific format (INTeINT)

Comment: Can you show the content of `A_Typedef.h` please?

Comment: what is the output of the warning `MyMSG`?

Comment: The output of the warning MyMSG is right, the expected string: 3686e892

Comment: If I define manually GITVER=3686e892  A_Typedef.h don't fails. So I assume the fail is not on it

Comment: warchantua, thank you, right, if I define manually GITVER=0x3686e892, the warning is out, so the question is, how can i turn the console string output into Hexadecimal?

Comment: Why would you parse git revisions as a double floating point number? `COMMAND bash -c "git rev-parse --short HEAD"` just `COMMAND git rev-parse --short HEAD`, there's no point in bash... Please show a [MCVE] - from what you present, I think it should work. The only case I suspect is that `GIT_VAR` has a trailing newline - research `execute_process` how to remove that newline.

Comment: @KamilCuk But I have no Idea haha, but, with your command, I get the same error :-(

Comment: @Jos try `GITVER="0x${GIT_VER}"`

Comment: @KamilCuk, you're right, there is an extra \n, that I muss suppress.

Comment: The interpretation as floating point is accidental and is due to the `e` in the hexadecimal representation of the short hash. Other short hashes would probably get treated differently. Putting the `0x` up front is OK, but watch out if you're still treating this numerically: even shortened hashes will grow longer over time as the repository expands and *may* eventually exceed 64 bits.

Comment: Slightly off topic: What would be a way to trigger this macro generation everytime I call make? Right now cmake executes it once we do cmake. All subsequent calls to make just resuse the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
execute_process (
    COMMAND bash -c "git rev-parse --short HEAD"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_VER
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

target_compile_definitions(LibDEFINES PRIVATE
    GITVER="0x${GIT_VER}"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution!!!! Thank you very much all, special thanks to @KamilCuk and @warchantua

```
execute_process (
    COMMAND git rev-parse --short HEAD
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_VER
)
string(STRIP ${GIT_VER} GIT_VER)    #to remove the "\n" at the end

target_compile_definitions(LibDEFINES PRIVATE
    GITVER=0x${GIT_VER}
)
```